# How to make slider infinite?

Tags: html, css, slider

I try to make infinite slider in HTML/CSS, so I found solution. It works fine but it's not infinite. I am using [THIS](https://codepen.io/jackoliver/pen/qVbQqW) solution, I just change the size of the images. Where's the problem? It can't be solved just changing sizes?

I tried to use another sizes of the images but it doesn't work.

Thank you :-)

```css
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-webkit-calc(-190px *6));
                transform: translateX(calc(-190px *6));
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
             transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-moz-calc(-190px *6));
             transform: translateX(calc(-190px *6));
    }
}

@-o-keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
           transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: translateX(calc(-190px *6));
           transform: translateX(calc(-190px *6));
    }
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
           -moz-transform: translateX(0);
             -o-transform: translateX(0);
                transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-webkit-calc(-190px *6));
           -moz-transform: translateX(-moz-calc(-190px *6));
             -o-transform: translateX(calc(-190px *6));
                transform: translateX(calc(-190px *6));
    }
}

.slider {
    height: 105px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}

.slider .slide-track {
    -webkit-animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
            animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: flex;
    width: -webkit-calc(190px *6);
    width: -moz-calc(190px *6);
    width: calc(190px *6);
}

.slider .slide {
    height: 105px;
    width: 140px;
 padding: 0px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="slide-track">
<div class="slide"><a href="https://www.psimafie.cz/znacka/primordial-pet-food/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/1.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/orijen/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/2.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/goodstuff/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/3.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/taste-of-the-wild/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/4.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/magnusson/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/5.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/n-d/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/6.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/nutra-gold/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/7.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/essentialfoods/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/8.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/calibra/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/9.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/acana/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/10.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/vyhledavani/?string=marp"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/11.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/vyhledavani/?string=Brit"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/12.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer do the trick or is there another issue? Please let me know so I can help you out.

Comment: I solved this with another way :-) But I am sure that your solution works too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I figured out what's wrong, your HTML and CSS are fine except for the fact you need to place all the images twice in your HTML. Take a look at the code pen you linked in your question. They have 7 images but in their HTML they use 14, you use 12 so put 24 in your html like this:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slide-track">
<div class="slide"><a href="https://www.psimafie.cz/znacka/primordial-pet-food/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/1.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/orijen/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/2.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/goodstuff/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/3.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/taste-of-the-wild/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/4.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/magnusson/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/5.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/n-d/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/6.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/nutra-gold/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/7.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/essentialfoods/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/8.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/calibra/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/9.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/acana/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/10.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/vyhledavani/?string=marp"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/11.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/vyhledavani/?string=Brit"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/12.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
    <div class="slide"><a href="https://www.psimafie.cz/znacka/primordial-pet-food/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/1.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/orijen/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/2.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/goodstuff/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/3.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/taste-of-the-wild/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/4.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/magnusson/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/5.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/n-d/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/6.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/nutra-gold/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/7.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/essentialfoods/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/8.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/calibra/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/9.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/znacka/acana/"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/10.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/vyhledavani/?string=marp"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/11.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="/vyhledavani/?string=Brit"><img src="https://www.psimafie.cz/user/documents/upload/gallery/12.png" width="140" height="105" /></a></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Not 100% sure if this is an answer to your question but let me know whether it is or not. Hope this helps!